# Create new instance of javascript custom app

Tags: javascript, jquery

Been tasked with creating a marquee style slider but with some heavier functionality.

I have some code mocked up:

```
var $app = {
    slider = {
        init: function() {
            // run slider
        }
    }
}

$app.slider.init();
```

This works, but I need to also run another version of this 'slider' plugin at the same time without overwriting the variables I am creating inside it etc.

I though by adding in e.g.

```
init: function() {
    // after a certain requirement is met
    $app.slider.init();
}
```

I thought that would create another instance as per say but instead just seems to reinitialise what I am currently using. With the code structure as I have it, is there anyway to run a new instance of the slider 'plugin' ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use constructor functions to create a new instance of an object.

```
var $app = {
    slider: function(){
        this.init = function() {
            // run slider
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var slider1 = new $app.slider();
slider1.init();

var slider2 = new $app.slider();
slider2.init();
```

Also for saving memory, you can put the init function in the prototype of the constructor function.

```
$app.slider.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        // run slider
    }
}
```